# Magento 2 getting error Source class "\Magento\Framework\Filter\Zend" for "Magento\Framework\Filter\ZendFactory" generation does not exist

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, core, regenerate

I am getting this error on the checkout page

> Source class "\Magento\Framework\Filter\Zend" for
>   "Magento\Framework\Filter\ZendFactory" generation does not exist.

I deleted var folder
I deleted the generation folder
I run di compile cmd nothing working 
but nothing working for me plz need a mentoring.

we tried in both ssh and in a manual way. but still cache folder is not deleting.

if it deletes also, within a minute cache folder will recreate with all following folders.

> mage-0, mage-1, mage-2............ mage-9 , mage-a, mage-b,

I run di compile cmd nothing working 
but nothing working for me plz need a mentoring.

> mage-c....etc

Comment: your question title says Magento 2 but in the question context it is magento 1.9, please clarify your question

Comment: You should not get that message. The class `Magento\Framework\Filter\ZendFactory` should exist int he core `vendor/magento/framework/Filter/ZendFactory.php` and it should not require autogeneration

Comment: Can you check your wording as the error you have put in place is not a magento 1.9 issue as far as i can see

Comment: within your ssh terminal, from the magento root run 'php bin/magento setup:upgrade' also 'php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f' finally run 'php bin/magneto setup:di:compile before doing this make sure your folders have the correct permissions if you run these and the directories are not created correctly the i would suggest sudoing up. if that then works you know your issue lies with your permissions

Comment: issue is that this is not creating \Magento\Framework\Filter\Zend in generation folder i am working on local how i give permission??

Comment: if your problem is about giving or setting permission you can directly right click on the directory then go to its properties tab uncheck the "Read Only" attribute then save